# Google Colab - redirect_url for Google Drive API - OAuth 2.0

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-colaboratory

On Google Colab, I want to download a specific revision of a file from Google Drive to my workspace, however I found it extremely difficult (comparing how easy is to mount the drive).

I have created OAuth 2.0 Client ID, added 'expected' redirect_url's and uploaded the client_secrets.json to my workspace. And trying to download the revision with this script:

```
import requests
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

# Set up the OAuth flow
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

# Start the OAuth authorization process
credentials = flow.run_local_server(host='localhost',
    port=8081, 
    authorization_prompt_message='Please visit this URL: {url}', 
    success_message='The auth flow is complete; you may close this window.',
    open_browser=True)

# Save the credentials to a file
credentials.save_to_disk('credentials.json')

# Make an HTTP GET request to the selfLink URL
# I was able to fetch the FILE_ID and REVISION_ID both from download link given on Google Drive's UI
# ...and on developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3

self_link = f'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FILE_ID}/revisions/{REVISION_ID}'
response = requests.get(self_link, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.token})

# Save the response content as the downloaded file
with open('your_file_name', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

However, on `flow.run_local_server` step, when I visit the authentication link, I'm getting `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`, where the request detail is:
`redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/`.

I have no idea how to make this work, I have waited from 5 mins to hours to let Google workspace to save my redirect url, left out the ports, tried different ports, removed http, removed trailing backslash, used `postmessage` in the code for host (there is no way to register postmessage in the OAuth manager as it expects a URI).

I have also tried to use the Google API like this, and in this case, I am getting `file not found` error:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
files = drive_service.revisions().get_media(fileID=FILE_ID, revisionID=REVISION_ID).execute()
```

I have followed this suggested material as well:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-installed.md

Anybody has an idea (or a workaround) to download a revision of a file from Drive into Google Colab workspace?
P.S: As a workaround, I am not able to delete the revisions manually until the revision I want, probably due to storage constraints on Drive side. This will be a topic of another question I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in google cloud console for your project add the following as a redirect URI

> http://localhost:8081/

Comment: Do you mean here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient ?

It's already added.

Comment: It worked after I have added the trailing '/', and running the script again after first failure.